# Create an HTML table using Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

parse the given array (using JavaScript) and create an HTML table

- Gmail - containing all email ids with domain gmail.com.
- Yahoo - containing all email ids with domain yahoo.com.
- Others - containing all email ids with domains not in  a,b, and c, i.e., NOT gmail, hotmail and yahoo.

I want to segregate the array of emailids based on domain and show them in html table. I have tried the following code , but it doesnt work at if condition. Please help me solve this problem or alternate solution

```
----------    
    <script>
        // var email ="test@gmail.com"
        //  var domain = email.replace(/.*@/," ");
        //  alert(domain);

        var d1 = "gmail.com"
        var d2 = "hotmail.com"
        var d3 = "yahoo.com"
        var email =[" test@gmail.com", "test@hotmail.com" , "test@yahoo.com"];
        var i;
        // var domain = email.replace(/.*@/," ");
        var text = "";
        for(i=0;i<email.length;i++){
            var dom = email[i].replace(/.*@/," ");
            if(dom[i]==d1){
              // text += email[i] + "<br>";

              // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
              document.write("hii hello");
            }
            // else if(dom == "hotmail.com"){
      //         // text += email[i] + "<br>";

      //         // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      //         document.write("hii");
            // }
            // else if(dom == "yahoo.com"){
      //         // text += email[i] + "<br>";

      //         // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      //         document.write("swax");
            // }
            else{
                document.write(dom);        }
        }
        // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
        </script>
```

Comment: i want a solution in this format. 
test0@gmail.com test11@hotmail.com
test1@gmail.com test12@hotmail.com
test2@gmail.com test13@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

.replace(/.*@/," ");

You should replace with an empty string

```
.replace(/.*@/,"");
```

By the way, it's not really recommended to use document.write().
To help you I wrote quickly this snippet as starting point for you (no judgement, I barely tested it):

```
  function createTable(rows) {
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    for (row of rows) {
      const tr = document.createElement('tr');
      for (column of row) {
        const td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(column));
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      table.appendChild(tr);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(table);
  }
  const emails = [
    'test0@gmail.com', 'test0@hotmail.com', 'test0@test.com',
    'test1@gmail.com', 'test1@hotmail.com', 'test1@test.com',
  ];
  const split = [[], [], []];
  emails.forEach(email => {
    switch (email.split('@')[1]) {
      case 'gmail.com': split[0].push(email); break;
      case 'hotmail.com': split[1].push(email); break;
      default: split[2].push(email)
    }
  });
  createTable(split);
```

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: i want a solution in this format. 
test0@gmail.com test11@hotmail.com
test1@gmail.com test12@hotmail.com
test2@gmail.com test13@hotmail.com

Comment: for (row of rows)

is the equivalent of

 for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { const row = rows[i]; }